# Android - Widget RemoteView setImageViewBitmap from downloaded resource

Tags: android, multithreading, image, download, widget

I have a widget that fills a list with some downloaded information, which includes an image downloaded from a given URL.

I want to display this image using setImageViewBitmap with a bitmap created from the URL. I can successfully create the bitmap, but i face a problem:

When i use:

```
itmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(item.getPosterUrl()).getContent());
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.list_item.poster, bitmap);
```

The image is successfully shown on the widget list, however the download is kind of slow (and in general this should be done in any network operation) so i wanted to use a thread to perform the download on background while user can see the rest of the list.

My problem is that when i use the thread, the download is performed well but the remoteViews is not updating the image. I tried also with a Handler with the same result.

Maybe I need something as runOnUIThread but i didn't find a similar method for widget.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Download the image.

Step #2: When the download is complete, then update the app widget, using the image, via a `RemoteViews` and an `AppWidgetManager`

**UPDATE**

To clarify a bit, you cannot reliably download something directly in an `AppWidgetProvider` -- `onUpdate()` is called on the main application thread, and so the download may take too long.

However, `onUpdate()` can delegate its work to an `IntentService` that downloads the image and updates the app widget itself. `AppWidgetProvider` is a *place* to update an app widget, but other code in your app can update the app widget too. Just have your `IntentService` create the `RemoteViews`, obtain an `AppWidgetManager`, and do the update.

Comment: if i want to update multiple remoteviews basically a list of contacts with photos, how can i do that. I tried the method mentioned above, but it always updates the first view. Could you please help me? For ex: In my widget i have 5 contacts displayed. I loaded each photo and called appwidgetmgr.update everytime. It always updating the first item.

Comment: @meher: This is not directly related to the original question, or my answer. Please ask a new question via the Ask Question button in the upper right corner.